# HTTP Post from ios sdk

Tags: ios, goo.gl

I will have to make the HTTP post call in iOS sdk,

curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'

Any help on this?

Comment: There are probably at least 2309823094832 answers to this question on this site.  Did you look at any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of answers to this available here and via google. However here's a code sample. If you need more info please do a deeper search.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:POST_TARGET_URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // set the method to post
[theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",QUERY_VALUE_BOUNDRY] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *queryData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in [queryDict allKeys]) { // iterate the keys in an NSDictionary to build the post data with key/value pairs
    [queryData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\n\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [queryData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [queryDict objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [queryData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n--%@\n", QUERY_VALUE_BOUNDRY] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // begin bounds
}

[theRequest setHTTPBody:queryData]; // set the data object to the body of the post request

_URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self]; // open an NSURLConnection with the request that was just constructed.
```